# Hive queries - "MINUS"

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am new to Hive. I want to compare two tables and their data and get the data which are not matching. In SQL, we can do this using "MINUS", but it's not supported in Hive. So I want to know the different ways that will get my job done.

Comment: matching two tables means a lot of thing, could you please explain what you want to example ?

Comment: Please have a look at this answer about tables compare using full join: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837372/2700344

Comment: There are two tables-source and target. So I want those records that are extra in source table after a given condition. When the given condition is applied then those records shouldn't be in target but are still there. I want to know the various ways to find those records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive QL Except clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889029/hive-ql-except-clause)

Comment: MINUS is an Oracle extension. Corresponding ANSI SQL standard keyword is EXCEPT.